# .Net cookies for subdomains

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies

I'm trying to login a user on two subdomains.

Consider these subdomains:

forum.mydomain.com, account_a.mydomain.com, account_b.mydomain.com.

A user logs in to account_a.mydomain.com. In my authentication function i want to create an authentication cookie for forum.mydomain.com. (but not(!) for account_b.mydomain.com)

I tried creating a cookie and settings the .domain property to forum.mydomain.com but somehow the cookie isnt created. Settings the .domain property to .mydomain.com is not what i want because it would create a security problem since account_a and account_b are two completely different users.

How can i get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that can create a specific domain cookie is a machine that resolves on the domain you're creating. If you want to create a cookie called `account_a.mydomain.com` then your server's url must be accessed from that specific domain. Given this, it is not possible for `account_a.mydomain.com` to create a cookie specific to `forum.mydomain.com` because they are completely separate addresses. Any attempt to create such a cookie would actually create a cookie for `account_a.forum.mydomain.com`.

As for how to get it to work, you haven't really specified why you're tinkering with the cookie in this manner in the first place so that's difficult to say. You can only have one valid authentication cookie for a user per browser, and the cookies are common to all instances of a browser so it wouldn't really be possible to have a cookie for account_a validate for account_b, and the two cookies couldn't live on the same machine anyway. One of the purposes of domain level authentication is to prevent this kind of simultaneous multiplicity.

**Edit:** *(response to comment)*

In the scenario where you want a user to be able to travel across to multiple domain servers you don't need to touch the cookie itself. It will automatically bind itself to the `mydomain.com` domain and allow such a traversal. Attempting to apply an individual system level security mechanism on the global object is just a little backwards. To use an analogy, you wouldn't line the fence around your house with barbed wire to keep someone out of your basement. The authentication controls to prevent `account_a` from accessing the `account_b` domain needs to be applied at that server level. My guess is that you have some form of common code where the domain is rationalized against the authentication, so what you really need to do is handle the actual authorization.

One method would be to add some custom code to the Init or Load events of your Page baseclass. Also, you could add a piece of logic to the `BeginRequest` event in your global.asax. One technique I've seen used (though never used it myself), is to add to the AuthorizeRequest event in the global.asax. I wasn't able to find any documents describing the topic, but I did find one that shows an example of how it's done. https://nport.svn.codeplex.com/svn/jacky/ccs/CCWeb/Global.asax.cs

Comment: When a user from account_a or account_b logs in and wants to access the forum i dont want him to have to log in again. They are two different .net applications on my server.

Comment: @Jeroen: My response is too much for a comment. I will update my answer.

Comment: I get it. I will have to bind the cookie to .mydomain.com. But that way i can only be logged in to 1 account at once. Some of my users though can be logged in to multiple accounts at once. I could solve that by using an account specific name for the cookie?

Comment: You should never have a single user logged into multiple accounts simultaneously. It defeats the purpose of authentication. If you have a need for a single user to access multiple resources you should be using roles to grant access.

Answer (score 2):

You can't solve this with cookie settings alone, the purpose of the domain property is to prevent this.

If both forum.mydomain.com and account_a.mydomain.com absolutely needs to use the same authentication cookie, you need to set it to .mydomain.com and have some logic make sure it's not valid in account_b.mydomain.com